# Rselenium and portable Opera

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm trying to start portable Opera(x64 84.0.4316.31) use Rselenium.
On [GitHub](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases) operachromiumdriver I downloaded (x64 98.0.4758.82 driver for version 84)

Сonnection attempt

```
 se <- wdman::selenium(
    check = FALSE,
    jvmargs = list(
    opera =
      paste0(
       "-Dwebdriver.opera.driver=",
       normalizePath(
       
       #set driver path 
      "J:/Download/operadriver_win64/operadriver_win64/operadriver.exe"
      )
    )
   ))

  rd <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", port = 4568L, extraCapabilities = list(
   `moz:firefoxOptions` = list(
      
      # set exe path
      binary ="J:/Download/Opera/opera.exe"  
    )
  )) 

  rd$open()
```

Output

`Error in checkError(res) :  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4568: Connection refused`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it might help if you replace `port = 4568L` with `port = netstat::free_port()` so you are sure you are using an open port.

Comment: I'm sure that's not the problem.
when I use other browser - all working correct